# How can I encrypt a folder in OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos

If possible, how can I encrypt a folder with a password on OS X Mavericks?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OS X doesn't ship with a folder by folder encryption. You can create an encrypted sparse bundle which acts as a folder that is decrypted once it mounts and stores all contents in an encrypted form on disk.

1. Enable advanced image options in Disk Utility:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility advanced-image-options 1
   ```
2. Open Disk Utility (found in `/Applications/Utilities/`).
3. Select **File** → **New** → **Disk Image from Folder…** or press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.
4. Select the folder that contains your files and press **Image**.
5. Choose **sparsebundle** as the Image Format, and choose the level of encryption you require.

   [image]
6. Choose a password to encrypt the image. Make sure to uncheck the **Remember password in my Keychain** box if you want to be prompted each time you attempt to mount the disk.
7. Click OK. Disk Utility will create a sparse bundle to hold your files. Don't forget to delete the original folder.

You can make an alias (or a symbolic link, symlink for short) to folders in the encrypted folder to hide much of the difference between a disk image and the actual encrypted folder if desired. Alternatively, you can mount this disk image in a custom folder (instead of /Volumes) for even smoother access.

Comment: Or better: Mount it directly to the desired folder.

Comment: And it doesn't have to be sparse, does it?

Comment: @Max It doesn't have to be, but if it is, it will automatically expand to hold the contents.

Comment: But performance will be worse.

Comment: In Mavericks, the Image Format popup has changed. Choices are now "read-only", "read/write", among others. I'm guessing that "read/write" means sparse image.

Comment: @Dogweather I don't think so, because the folder size doesn't seem to expand. I get a "not enough free space" error when trying to add some large files. A workaround is to image a folder with more files than you need, then remove some after its done to free up space in the image.

Comment: @Dogweather I took that screenshot in Mavericks. Forgot to mention that you need advanced image options enabled—edited answer.

Comment: That's useful. With sparsebundle I still run into some arbitrary size limits on the image. I wonder where these come from. For example: encrypt a folder of some pdf's as a sparsebundle AES 256. Then mount the encrypted image and add a 1GB movie. Error not enough space. Does this happen for others?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to consider an app, there's a review on Tidbits of Hider 2:

http://tidbits.com/e/14740

In the comments are references to [Knox](https://agilebits.com/knox) and [Concealer](http://www.belightsoft.com/products/concealer/overview.php).